# ASP.NET Nested OOP Best Approach for Query Performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, nested

//option 1

```
public class division
{
    public int DivisionId { get; set; }
    public string DivisionName { get; set; }
    public employee Employee { get; set; }

    public class employee
    {
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }

        public employee(int id)
        {
            sql = new SqlCommand("select empid,empname from employee where divisionid = '" + id + "'", conn);
            conn.Open();
            dt = sql.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
            if (dt.Read())
            {
                EmpId = id;
                EmpName = (string)dt["empname"];
            }
            dt.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    public division(int id)
    {
        sql = new SqlCommand("select divisionid,divisionname from division where divisionid = '" + id + "'", conn);
        conn.Open();
        dt = sql.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
        if (dt.Read())
        {
            DivisionId = id;
            DivisionName = (string)dt["divisionname"];
            Employee = new employee((int)dt["divisionid"]);
        }
        dt.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

//option 2

```
public class division
{
    public int DivisionId { get; set; }
    public string DivisionName { get; set; }
    public employee Employee { get; set; }

    public class employee
    {
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string EmpName { get; set; }

        public employee()
        {
        }
    }
    public division(int id)
    {
        sql = new SqlCommand("select divisionid,divisionname from division a join employee b on a.divisionid = b.divisionid where a.divisionid = '" + id + "'", conn);
        conn.Open();
        dt = sql.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
        if (dt.Read())
        {
            DivisionId = id;
            DivisionName = (string)dt["divisionname"];
            Employee = new employee();
            Employee.EmpId = (int)dt["empid"];
            Employee.EmpName = (string)dt["empname"];
        }
        dt.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

The question I want to ask is, which of these two snippets perform better.

The first method, which made it convenient to call each Attribute on the class, but it require a nested connection to call the class and its attribute.
Example(option1), 2 roundtrip to database, first one is when we call Division, and the second connection is when we call Employee.
But SQL required for each connection trip to database is very convenient to code(simple and shorter).

The second method, using the join query to call employee from each division.
It only require 1 roundtrip to database but with more complicated code.

These example are a simple form of Nested OOP, but what happened when the related table are complicated(eg. 5-6 table relationship), which means we need a long and complicated query using join for each table.

Comment: How about using SQL stored procedure to handle data and keep uniform result set at all times?

Comment: "which of these two snippets perform better.". Why don't you test this yourself?

Comment: It is a reasonable approach, but I have several question in mind.

Example, we have Table A, Table B, Table C, Table D, Table E which have interconnected relationship

If we need a field from table A and table B, we need to create a query to join table A-B.
If we need a field from table A and table C, we need to create a query to join table A-C.

Wasn't that is a waste of time, but with the OOP class Approach, we only need to call : Division.employeeName(id) to get a field we want without involving any complicated query.

Comment: @Steven The result without a massive data and multiple concurrent connection won't be accurate, and I'm not likely able to have those requirement. Thank you.

Comment: Get your pro tool out and create massive test data with atest data generator. Taeks half an hour.

Comment: can you kindly tell me what kind of pro tool i can use, because i am not familiar with the term of pro tool. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The roundtrips to the database are expensive, so the second option performs better. If you need the join to perform better, add an index on `divisionid` column of the `employee` table.

The second option is kind wrong now, maybe you didn't show here the latest version of it. Instead of

```
sql = new SqlCommand("select divisionid,divisionname from ..
```

it should be

```
sql = new SqlCommand("select a.divisionid, divisionname, empid, empname  from ..
```

Are you sure the division has only one employee?

Comment: Of course the division has many employee. That is just an example, because what i really want to know whether i really need to make myself to code complicated query or not. Because if i am using option 1, each class manage it's own properties. So, i didn't need to use join in query, because i only need to write simple query for each table, but if i am using option 2 , the more table i am using, the more complicated the query will be, which i want to avoid

Comment: ORMs like LINQ 2 SQL or EF try to use one query when possible. So if you want to load a division and all its employess, the ORM will do it in a query ( or at least of you have instructions to ask the ORM to do it). I would really trust them, they already did performance tests.